# java cannot create mutex in the IDEA

Tags: java, apache-tika

I run the tika-src-code in the IDEA with the -g. After I parse a file the console log the followig log.What's more,if I run the tika-app-1.16.jar in the command it appears too.But I run the same jar in another computer that won't happen.What to do for dealing this?

> [2018- 2- 7  9: 4:9] UDX::Open - cannot create mutex [2018- 2- 7  9: 4:9] >IHX::Open - cannot create mutex [2018- 2- 7  9: 4:9] UDX::Open
>   -    cannot get owner of mutex [2018- 2- 7  9: 4:9] IHX::Open - cannot    gain >owner of mutex

Comment: If you can reproduce the error in the command line why do you think it is IDEA related ?

Comment: emmm,I found it appears in the IDEA firstly.Is this related command?I really don't know about this case.